# How to convert SGML to (La)Tex

Tags: conversion

I find a great open source book -- *Advanced Bash-Scripting Guide*, which has been published [online](http://www.tldp.org/guides.html) in various formats but LaTex. Although it comes with an compiled PDF version, I prefer to compile myself from Tex file, in part because that PDF is really no-so-well formatted (at least, not Tex style).

A seemingly workable way is **SGML to Tex**, can you guys suggest some tools to accomplish this conversion?

Answer (score 2):

This is one of solutions: http://manned.org/sgml2latex/70c2f6bc. It is an obsolete version. In Linux it is recommended to use `linuxdoc -B latex`.